# How to sort an array then take the index and use the index to move all corresponding elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have 5 different arrays that have the same index, eg:

```
person[0]="john", address[0]= "Druid Valley", city[0]="Atlanta", amount[0]=2000, need[0]=100; 
person[1]="emily", address[1]="50 decatur", city[1]="Chicago", amount[1]=300; need[1]=50;
```

I need to reorder all arrays in the descending order  of the need[] array then re-arrange the order of the other arrays based on new index for need[i]. I'm using javascript.

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 1):

Sort the `need` array and save the sort permutation, then apply that permutation to the other arrays. How exactly you do this depends upon the language you're using. For instance, the Matlab `sort` function can return both the sorted array and the sorting permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't sort "need". Create an index array, then sort that one according to need. You didn't specify the language though, so you're getting JavaScript:

```
var person = [], need = [];

var person = ["E", "B", "A", "C", "D"];
var need = [111, 444, 555, 333, 222];

var index = [];
var i = person.length;
while (i--) {
  index.push(i);
}
var comparator = function(a, b) {
  var need_a = need[a];
  var need_b = need[b];

  // For robustness - non-numbers get sorted last:
  if (typeof need_a != 'number' || isNaN(need_a)) need_a = -Infinity;
  if (typeof need_b != 'number' || isNaN(need_b)) need_b = -Infinity;

  if (need_a < need_b) return 1;
  if (need_b < need_a) return -1;
  return 0;
}
index.sort(comparator);

// at this point, person[index[0]] is the person with the biggest need.

var sorted_person = [];
var i = index.length;
while (i--) {
  sorted_person[i] = person[index[i]];
}

// at this point, sorted_person[0] is the person with the biggest need.

console.log(sorted_person);
```

Comment: Thank you Amadan, it was the Javascript language (that I should have specified from the beginning) - how would I use this to reorder all the arrays at the same time, not just person? I need something that would reorder all of them at the same time (while cycling through the elements).

Comment: You probably don't need to - just use the original arrays with the `index` index, like I show in the last line. If you really need them as sorted arrays, making new ones would be easier: `var i = index.length; var sorted_person = [], sorted_address = []; while (i--) { sorted_person[i] = person[index[i]]; sorted_address[i] = address[index[i]]; }`

Comment: I tried this, sorting does not work, I am getting values that are not sorted.

Comment: Erm, works here. I'll update the code to show the added bit, and replace your arrays with something where it's easier to see the result.

Comment: Thank you Amadan, your code works with what you wrote. The problem that I noticed that out of let's say~  800 elements there may be ~ 20-50 that will either have "NaN" (these were taken from a web based form and parseFloat did not work since they were probably empty fields at the time). What should I change to allow for such values in need[]?

Comment: Changed with your scenario. Again, I don't know what you want with the `NaN`s, so I put them at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

make a copy array that will have same values as in need array (call him sorted array).
then look at the original need array - and for every cell find where it is at the sorted array and put the matching values from other arrays to the same cell number that they appear at the sorted array

Comment: Can you please paste in the code that would do what you are saying? I am a beginner and practical details help me understand. Thank you.