# Sorting a numeric array along with an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I generate two arrays
One that holds Array of numbers:

```
[5.65, 3.25, 4.34, 6.78]
```

And another array that holds objects with some information in them

```
[car.object1, car.object2, car.object3, car.object4]
```

And the objects in second array are related to the numbers in first array. So object1 is related to 5.65, object2 to 3.25 and so on.

So I want to sort the array 1 in an ascending order and at the same time sort the array 2 also.

So the **result** should be:

```
[3.25, 4.34, 5.65, 6.78]
```

&

```
[car.object2, car.object3, car.object1, car.object4]
```

**My Approach:** (You can just ignore the below answer as I think it is wrong. It does not work.)

```js
var all = [];
var A = [5.65, 3.25, 4.34, 6.78];
var B = ['store.object1', 'store.object2', 'store.object3', 'store.object4'];

for (var i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
  all.push({
    'A': A[i],
    'B': B[i]
  });
}

all.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.A - b.A;
});

A = [];
B = [];

for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  A.push(all[i].A);
  B.push(all[i].B);
}

console.log(A, B);
```

Comment: you may consider to use arrays with `[]` instead of obejcts with `{}`.

Comment: Are you sure those are arrays not objects? They are not valid arrays nor valid objects by the way!

Comment: Now it should work I guess!

Comment: Yep it's working!

Comment: Yes it is. Just checked on fiddle. Thanks

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Just FYI, that deleted answer as Java, not C++. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder haha :-) I thought only C++ has type templates. Totally fooled by that syntax!

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312236/how-to-sort-an-array-then-take-the-index-and-use-the-index-to-move-all-correspon , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499268/sort-two-arrays-the-same-way , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960105/sorting-multiple-arrays-at-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to implement the sort yourself, one simple way is to combine the entries from the number array with the entries from the object array (at least briefly), sort that, and then (if necessary) extract the result:

```js
// Setup
var car = {
  object1: {name: "object1"},
  object2: {name: "object2"},
  object3: {name: "object3"},
  object4: {name: "object4"}
};
var nums = [5.65, 3.25, 4.34, 6.78];
var objs = [car.object1, car.object2, car.object3, car.object4];

// Combine
var joined = [];
nums.forEach(function(num, index) {
  joined[index] = {num: num, object: objs[index]};
});

// Sort
joined.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.num - b.num;
});

// Extract
nums = [];
objs = [];
joined.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  nums[index] = entry.num;
  objs[index] = entry.object;
});

console.log(nums);
console.log(objs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

But rather than combine, sort, and extract, I'd probably just maintain a single array and add each number to its relevant object, so they always travel together.

Comment: I just realized this is basically the solution in the question. I'm afraid I took the *"You can just ignore the below answer as I think it is wrong. It does not work."* to heart and skipped right over it. Later I saw the comments between you and ibrahim and looked it it.

Comment: What does it exactly mean?

Comment: @Kinduser: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes. May be the answer is correct. I am still checking with my code here what I did wrong.

Comment: Finally I used your snippet. To be honest. I am new to JavaScript and I guess could not debug my code here. So just used your's. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am now trying to understand how everything works. And also thanks for the idea of having both the data together in one array. I tried that in the beginning. But just because I didn't figure out how to separate them later. I choose to keep them separate. DEADLINE pressure. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a temporary array with the indices and sort it with the values of the first array. Then map the sorted array with the values of `array1` and `array2`.

I use strings for the second array, instead of missing objects.

```js
var array1 = [5.65, 3.25, 4.34, 6.78],
    array2 = ['car.object1', 'car.object2', 'car.object3', 'car.object4'],
    temp = array1.map(function (_, i) { return i; });

temp.sort(function (a, b) { return array1[a] - array1[b]; });

array1 = temp.map(function (a) { return array1[a]; });
array2 = temp.map(function (a) { return array2[a]; });

console.log(temp);
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. And after looking at your syntax, corrected mine. And that works too,

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ES6 way to do it:

```js
let a = [5.65, 3.25, 4.34, 6.78];
let b = [{ x:1 }, { x:2 }, { x:3 }, { x: 4}];

[a, b] = a.map( (n, i) => [n, b[i]] ) // zip the two arrays together
          .sort( ([n], [m]) => n-m ) // sort the zipped array by number
          .reduce ( ([a,b], [n, o]) => [[...a, n], [...b, o]], [[],[]] ); // unzip 

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've helped myself with an object containing `car.object` as the key and it's `number` as the value. Seems easy&quick solution.

```js
var obj = [{'car.object1': 5.65}, {'car.object2': 3.25}, {'car.object3': 4.34}, {'car.object4': 6.78}],
    objs = obj.sort((a,b) => a[Object.keys(a)] - b[Object.keys(b)]);
    
    console.log(objs.map(v => Object.keys(v)[0]));
    console.log(objs.map(v => v[Object.keys(v)]));
    console.log(objs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just DV me without a word

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually the starting point is the same in every answer. In one of them the next step is map, or forEach or sort. My next step was to drop these arrays into an object. I don't really see anything wrong in it (: